# Issue with minified LESS CSS code

Tags: css, less

I have some code that is not rendering correctly in the minified output.

Here's the basics:

I have a mixin:

```
.Aspect(@widthRatio:16; @heightRatio:9; @useableWidth:100%) {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:@useableWidth;

    &::before {
        content:"";
        float:left;
        padding-top:percentage(@heightRatio / @widthRatio);
    }
}
```

... and some styles:

```
.backdrop {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;

    .Aspect(1; 1);

    .Landscape({
        .Aspect(16; 9);
    });
}

.app-bar-spacer-3 {
    height:250px!important;
    background-color:Lime;
}
```

Here's what's happening.

The `.app-bar-spacer-3` style is not working, however it's due to the rendering of the previous style `.backdrop`.

I can make it go away by removing the pseudo element in `.Aspect()` but obviously that isn't a fix.

The code seems ok in the none minified stylesheet but on inspection in Chrome, this is what is being output:

```
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.backdrop::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  .backdrop {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .backdrop::before {
    content: "";float:left;padding-top:56.25%}.app-bar-spacer-3{height:250px!important;background-color:#0f0}
```

There's actually more but as you can see all the code following is being output inside the curly brackets belonging to the pseudo element.

I've looked at it so long I'm not sure whether it's my code or LESS.

Anyone advise?

Comment: Having looked at the code output, I've already noticed one thing that breaks the flow - double quotation marks. However, this is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much, much testing, I found the root cause of the issue.

It does in fact eminate from code further up the stylesheet, but doesn't actually break until it hits the above code.

Here's the code that broke LESS:

```
.md-text-tab {
    &:not(:last-child)::after {
        content:'\\';
    }
}
```

More specifically, it's the escaped slash.